# Does Zend provide an object wrapper for Zend_XmlRpc return values?

Tags: xml, zend-framework, xml-rpc, zend-xmlrpc

I have something like:

```
$client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('<XML-RPC URL>');
$result = $client->call('<method name>', array( ... ));
```

I get an XML string in `$result`.  Is Zend capable of marshalling this XML into some object or associative array?

If Zend doesn't marshall this automatically and I have to do so using plain PHP, how is it best done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meh. I'm settling for [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) (a PHP5 module), as suggested [here](http://www.zfforums.com/zend-framework-extensions-integration-third-party-35/integration-third-party-tools-34/xml-parser-zend-framework-9.html#post13). I don't need anything complex anyway.